# Django ProgrammingError while migrations with django 1.8 and python2.7.11, mysql

Tags: django

I am getting following error while making migration to mysql database

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLES' at line 1")
```

I have checked my code but didn't found anything wrong.
Note: This is my first migration after creating django project

Comment: it's impossible to answer a question like this without the relevant code or more information

Comment: Have you configured your database backend properly in your local.py under settings?

Comment: @Azsgy I haven't coded anything yet. installed django 1.8 and started project and tried to run `python manage.py migrate` command. and got this error